# Creating padding between divs

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

Hi guys i am playing with a main div i got on my site and trying to make the div

I am using bootstrap etc and just seeing what i can do, i guess when i scale down the size etc everything became very bad but i guess i can use media queries to make it look better, my main question is on the right hand side i am trying to make gaps between the 4 divs, if someone can advise me how to that would be brilliant. Also if there is anther way that this can be done please let me know as i am learning and more knowledge = better for me :)

The main part is the :

```
<div class="righttBox">
</div>
```

That is what i am trying to get spaces between

Comment: floats, fixed widths and margins all play havoc with layout. Either change all your widths to percentages and make the necessary adjustments for margins or use flexbox

Comment: Are you using any of Bootstrap's built in layout helpers with their grid? I saw you used the container class in your fiddle, but I didn't see bootstrap's row or col-x-y classes (x being the type, and y being the number of columns). Could be that missed them, but if not, have you tried them yet? Using their grid may make your life easier, or at least be worth playing with.

Comment: add margins to inner div eventually https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/17626/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe have a look at this tutorial (Box-Model).
I rather think you need margins???

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp

look for float, float:left, float:right
and good luck!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think any layout problems you have can be solved with Bootstrap's built in grid, which makes laying things out pretty easy. On the whole, I think your specific question about adding spacing will be solved by using the grid.

For reference, here is the section of the documentation on their grid and layout system: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Here is my untested code that I think will set up the layout you are looking for:

```
<div class="container">
    <!-- CONTENT CONTAINER -->
    <div class="row">
        <!-- BEGIN LEFT COLUMN -->
        <div class="col-md-2">
            Put left column content here
        </div>
        <!-- END LEFT COLUMN -->

        <!-- BEGIN MAIN COLUMN -->
        <div class="col-md-8">
            Put main column content here
        </div>
        <!-- END MAIN COLUMN -->

        <!-- BEGIN RIGHT COLUMN -->
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <!-- BEGIN FIRST ROW IN RIGHT COLUMN -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    Put 1st right box content here
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- END FIRST ROW IN RIGHT COLUMN -->

            <!-- BEGIN SECOND ROW IN RIGHT COLUMN -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    Put 2nd right box content here
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- END SECOND ROW IN RIGHT COLUMN -->

            <!-- BEGIN THIRD ROW IN RIGHT COLUMN -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    Put 3rd right box content here
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- END THIRD ROW IN RIGHT COLUMN -->

            <!-- BEGIN FOURTH ROW IN RIGHT COLUMN -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    Put 4th right box content here
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- END FOURTH ROW IN RIGHT COLUMN -->
        </div>
        <!-- END RIGHT COLUMN -->
    </div>
    <!-- END CONTENT -->
</div>
```

Here's how it works:

Inside your container you define a row. In your diagram, this is the outermost black box.

Inside the row are 3 div's that serve as columns, becoming the left, middle, and right columns. The left and right columns use 2 grid columns each for a total of 4, which leaves 8 for the middle column. You can adjust this as needed, but they must not total more than 12 (because it's a 12-column grid).

For the right column, we have 4 rows, which accomplishes the 4 boxes, and then each of those has a div that serves as a column, because in Bootstrap I've found you want your content ultimately wrapped up in a column.

I should also mention that the 4 boxes on the right use all 12 grid columns, even though they are inside a column using only 2 (the right column). The reason for this is the grid is based on the width of the parent row. So in this case, col-md-12 means "use 100% of the width of my parent row", so that it fills the entire right column, even though the right column isn't 100% of the page's width.

I think with this layout, much of your padding woes will go away.

This assumes I've correctly interpreted your question of course, hopefully I have!

Answer (score 0):

`<div class="col-size-number"></div>`

col is `constant for column`
size is `lg` for large, `md` for medium, `sm` for small and `sx` for x-small
number range is `1 - 12`

for more info read http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid